# Rails: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting these params in the console:

```
category_id" # => ["", "14", "16", "17"]
```

When I check if the array is empty or not inside a model with this:

```
@category = category_id.any?
```

it returns the following error:

```
undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
```

I have the strong params like this:

```
:category_id => []
```

Any ideas on how to check if this array is empty or not?

```
def new
  @account = Account.new
  @categories.build
end

def create
  @account = Account.new(account_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @account.save
      format.html { redirect_to accounts_path, notice: 'Account was successfully added.' }
      format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @account }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:name, :street, :street_2, :city, :state, :postal_code, :country, category_id: []
end
```

console results:

```
"account"=>{"name"=>"", "street"=>"", "street_2"=>"", "city"=>"",  "state"=>"", "postal_code"=>"", "country"=>"", "category_id"=>["", "14", "15"]
```

Comment: I guess you meant `@category = params[:category_id].any?`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Marek Lipka... I'm getting this: undefined local variable or method `params'. the method which i'm trying to check the array is inside a model

Comment: params are not available in a model, only in controller, you need to pass them to a model method if you want to use it

Comment: Yea I know that @mrzasa.... This is what I'm doing to see if the array is empty or not inside a model `@category = category_id.try(:any?)  if @category === false `

Comment: @Dev Could you provide more controller code to see what is the actual issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zauzaj ... I just added the controller code to my original question, if you need anything else please let me know.

Comment: Try byebug debugger and check line by line. This is very helpful to know where things go wrong step by step without much guessing. Place it right after `def create`  and follow the params object.

Comment: @Dev Could you show `Account` model? Seems you don't have `category_id` field in accounts. Could you confirm that? Anyway you should show us method `category_id` where you're getting this exception.

Comment: Are you trying nested attributes?

Comment: Quite plainly put, category_id clearly doesn't exist, hence the NilError.

Where are you calling this `category_id.any?`  

When you say "console results" what do you mean? Is that the output of your `account_params` method?
Do you have any validations on the model itself?
Can you confirm the account model saves successfully?

Comment: @Stuart nitpicking, but `category_id` does exist – it has a value of `nil`. An undefined variable would result in a `NameError`.

Comment: @Stefan potato potato

Comment: you should check `params[:account][:category_id]`

Answer (score 0):

@variables are not available inside the model. Neither are the params.

It's good practice to not try to do so but here are some ways to do it:

**If you want to pass a value that is a database field/column:**

```
# In the controller
account = Account.new(:category => @category)

# In this example, :category is a database field/column of the 
# Account model, not sure if that's accurate for you.
```

**If not then you gotta use an attr_accessor like this:**

```
# In the model
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :category

#In the controller (this is equivalent to the first example)
account = Account.new
account.category = @category
```

Using attr_accessor doesn't save anything into the database, but the controller doesn't know the difference (which is good). This allows you to move data around like you wanted.